# EF Entity not updated in database

Tags: entity-framework

This is the code that I have in my controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult UpdateArticle(Article article)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           article.DateAdded = 
               this.articleRepository.GetSingle(article.ID).DateAdded;
           article.DateModified = DateTime.Now;

           this.articleRepository.Update(article);
               return this.Redirect("~/Admin");
       }
       else
       {
           return this.Redirect("~/Admin/UnsuccessfulOperation");
       }
   }
```

From the view the data comes updated. I have a generic repository which handles the saving.
Update looks like this:

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    //this.context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

    this.context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If I uncomment the first line

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple
>   objects with the same key.

exception is thrown. When commented nothing is saved.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Ok the problem seems to be that the updated article is not "part" of the context so when I pass it to the update nothing happens. If I get the entity from the repository itself and pass the new values and after that pass this entity everything works as expected. This piece of code actually updates the date in the repository:

```
var art = this.articleRepository.GetSingle(article.ID);
art.Text = article.Text;
this.articleRepository.Update(art);
```

What I don't get is that this works too:

```
var art = this.articleRepository.GetSingle(article.ID);
art.Text = article.Text;
this.articleRepository.Update(article);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to Vitaliy I now know that attaching is the key, but when I try to attach the new entity I get the same ugly exception

> An object with the same key already...

**UPDATE 3**

As I am not allowed to answer my own question in less than 8h I suppose I have to make another update.

Ok, so this is what I did in order to successfully detach the old and attach the new entity:

```
public virtual void Update(T entity, object id)
{
    this.context.Entry(this.GetSingle(id)).State = EntityState.Detached;
    this.context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    this.context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

    this.context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I will think of a better way to pass the ID, as it is already part of the entity, perhaps with and interface "myInterface" that has the ID property in it and T will be of type "myInterface".

Thanks a lot to Vitaliy.

Comment: There is any code where updates your entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating article, which is not attached to Context, thus nothing will be saved.
Probably you intention was to change DateModified then you should do it like this:

```
public ActionResult UpdateArticle(Guid articleID) 
   { 
       if (ModelState.IsValid) 
       { 
           var article =  
               this.articleRepository.GetSingle(articleID); 
           article.DateModified = DateTime.Now; 

           this.articleRepository.Update(article); 
               return this.Redirect("~/Admin"); 
       } 
       else 
       { 
           return this.Redirect("~/Admin/UnsuccessfulOperation"); 
       } 
   }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Actually the article from the view comes with updated values too. I am setting the dates on the server as they are not meant to be edited in any way by the users. What will be the best way to just attach the entity somehow? Or I just have to copy the values from the article parameter?

Comment: this.context.ArticleSet.Attach(article);
this.context.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified; this.context.SaveChanges();

Comment: A little bit ahead of you :). I am not able to detach the old entity so when I try to attach the new one it just throws the infamous error that an object with the same key already exists. I am trying to detach the old entity by id, like this: `this.context.Entry(this.GetSingle(id)).State = EntityState.Detached;`

Comment: I do not know how this happened, but it somehow worked, I have not done anything. However now the new values are again not saved, and I am attaching the new entity successfully - I can see the changes in the context, but I am not able to see them after that.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but most probably duplicate is created in you context within GetSingle() implementation. If you already have changed object you don't need it, just attach object that you have change it state as needed and fire SaveChanges.